# APPINSTALLER File (.appinstaller) - Is there a way to extract or convert to EXE.MSI

Tags: file-extension

I have an (.appinstaller) (file) application that I would like to be able to convert it to a traditional msi/exe package...

I cant seem to find anything out there...

Anyone able to help with this matter, thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, I found another way to better extract the needed files without converting..You run the package but you go until the very last step of the wizard but you dont install, go your temp folder and locate the msi, that way you dont have to worry about switches, command lines, dependecies...etc!!!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

made this account to add a comment on the answer by @harrymc but I don't have enough rep...

Your answer was very good but a bit simplistic.

What about the dependencies? Treat them the same as the other `msix` files? Will they know the correct path for the installation of said dependencies?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

An appinstaller file is just a textual XML file that says
how to install the application, or in other words it points
to the real installation file.
It does not contain the installation file.

The Microsoft article
[App Installer file overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/app-installer-file-overview)
gives this example scenario:

> 1. IT Pro Joe wants to distribute the Human Resources app to his enterprise.
> 2. IT Pro Joe puts the Human Resources app on a share and creates an App Installer file named HumanResources.appinstaller. This App
>    Installer file is associated with the app.
> 3. IT Pro Joe puts HumanResources.appinstaller on a share.
> 4. IT Pro Joe points the enterprise’s employees to HumanResources.appinstaller.
>
> - Manager Maggie clicks on HumanResources.appinstaller and gets the App Installer UI, which guides her to install the Human Resources
>   application.

The Github post
[Create an App Installer file manually](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msix-docs/blob/main/msix-src/app-installer/how-to-create-appinstaller-file.md)
contains this minimal appinstaller file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AppInstaller
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/appinstaller/2021"
    Version="1.0.0.0"
    Uri="http://mywebservice.azurewebsites.net/appset.appinstaller" >

    <MainPackage
        Name="Contoso.MainApp"
        Publisher="CN=Contoso"
        Version="2.23.12.43"
        ProcessorArchitecture="x64"
        Uri="http://mywebservice.azurewebsites.net/mainapp.msix" />

</AppInstaller>
```

This small file is enough to demonstrate the concept.
It describes how to use the installer package, which is
found in an MSIX file located at address
`http://mywebservice.azurewebsites.net/mainapp.msix`.

You should open your appinstaller file in a text editor,
find which file contains the real installer and use it,
as it will be an EXE or MSI file that contains the
entire installation.